# 8 Variables in one line (Batch)

Tags: batch-file, variables

I have tried multiple things with a code like this.

```
@echo off
set %1%=A
set %2%=B
set %3%=C
set %4%=D
set %5%=E
set %6%=F
set %7%=G
set %8%=H
echo %1%%2%%3%%4%%5%%6%%7%%8%%9%
```

But kinda nothing worked, the output was this:

```
1%2%3%4%5%6%7%8
```

How do I get it to output ABCDEFGH?

Comment: When you set variables, you **do not** enclose them in percentage signs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with

```
@echo off
set _1=A
set _2=B
set _3=C
set _4=D
set _5=E
set _6=F
set _7=G
set _8=H
echo %_1%%_2%%_3%%_4%%_5%%_6%%_7%%_8%
```

Starting from the concept, your problem is that `%n` with `n` in the range `0..9` is handled by the batch parser as an command line argument to the batch file, not a variable expansion operation.

You *can* use number prefixed variable names, but then you will require to enable delayed expansion and change the variable expansion syntax from `%varName%` in to `!varName!` to be able to retrieve the value. It is easier not use number prefixed variables names.

The second problem is that the syntax `%varName%` is only used where the variable value needs to be retrieved. When you set the value, the syntax is `set varName=varValue`, or still better you  can quote the operation as `set "varName=varValue"` to avoid problems with special characters and inclusion of unneeded ending spaces.

Comment: Thanks! Worked just great.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. The code below do *exactly* what you requested:

```
@echo off
set A=A
set B=B
set C=C
set D=D
set E=E
set F=F
set G=G
set H=H
echo %A%%B%%C%%D%%E%%F%%G%%H%
```

However, is likely that this obvious solution is not what you are looking for...

If you want to know if is there a way to "automatically" define a series of variables and process they all, then the solution is to use an *array*. You may read the description of the array concept in this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_structure) and a detailed explanation of array management in Batch files at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990). For example:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Create "a" array with all elements given:
set n=0
for %%a in (A B C D E F G H) do (
   set /A n=n+1
   set a[!n!]=%%a
)

rem Show the 8 elements of "a" array
echo %a[1]%%a[2]%%a[3]%%a[4]%%a[5]%%a[6]%%a[7]%%a[8]%

rem Join *all* the elements of "a" array in a single variable
set "all="
for /L %%i in (1,1,%n%) do set "all=!all!!a[%%i]!"

echo %all%
```

Note that the last example works correctly *no matters* how many elements have been defined in "a" array.

Although you may also write the array elements in a shorter way, ommiting the braquets: `set "a1=A" & set "a2=B"`, etc, and then use `echo %a1%%a2%...`, you should remember that the use of braquets is a standard notation used in many other programming languages, so it is convenient to keep it.